# VBA .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy" run-time error

Tags: vba, excel

When I use the below code to render HTML in cells, I receive a `"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"` on the line
`.document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy".`

Does anyone know of a fix or work-around?

```
Sub FormatHtmlViaIE()
Dim ie As Object, tr, c As Range

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Set tr = Range("B2:F500")
With ie
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    Do While .busy
    Loop

    For Each c In tr
        .document.body.innerHTML = c.Value
        .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
        Selection.Parent.Paste Destination:=c
    Next c
    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```